# Not able to connect ec2 instance of RDS bastion host using my home network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am generally able to connect with EC2 Instance by whitelisting my public ip in aws console in any network. This problem i face particularly with my home's wifi network. I have whitelisted my public ip but still not able to connect. Can any one suggest, what can be the issue?

Comment: The AWS console does not have a whitelisting feature. Access to your EC2 instance is controlled by security groups and NACLs. Edit your question and add both of these items.

Comment: When you say "whitelist", do you mean "add my IP address to the Inbound Security Group rules"? Also, why does your title mention RDS, but your question does not? Feel free to Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes I meant "add my IP address to the Inbound Security Group rules". I got it resolved by changing the inbound ip address port to 22 (eg: 14.168.0.14/22) for my home network. Due to some weird reasons, I am not able to connect with the default port (eg: 14.168.0.14/32) in my home network.

Comment: Please note that `14.168.0.14/22` **does not mean port 22**. Rather, then `/22` indicates a _range_ of IP addresses in [CIDR Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cidr). A security group needs a combination of a port (eg Port 22) and a range of IP addresses (eg `14.168.0.14/32`, which means just the one IP address of `14.168.0.14`).